# how can I write a char in an array of number

Tags: java, char, integer

I am working on a Tic-tac-toe Game 6x7(6 rows and 7 columns) so I display this to the user

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
22  23  24  25  26  27  28
29  30  31  32  33  34  35
36  37  38  39  40  41  42
```

then I want to ask the user to input 'X' or 'O' but the above numbers are in a 2D array of integers
and 'X' and 'O' are both chars how can I insert them in. I know I can use '0' and '1' instead but I am seeking to use 'x' and 'o'.

Comment: I would use an array of `Object[]` and just put `Integer` or `Character` in the array as needed.

Comment: You could use the ascii values of 'X' and 'O' maybe and then cast back to char when it is being displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't - why not just dynamically display the numbers (instead of storing them)? Try this:

- Create a grid of chars, where each cell stores either ' ' (space), 'X' or 'O'.
- Modify your print grid function so that when it encounters an empty cell (' '), it calculates it's "number" and displays it. `n = 7*x + y`
- On user input you can simply calculate the cell position `x = n / 7`, `y = n % 7`

Answer (score -1):

You could use string arrays to present the numbers also then change the same index with another string for example:

```
String[][] grid = new String[6][7];
```

then fill it with numbers that you use 1..42 in string format ("1","2","3"..)

when user enters a number use the index to access that array for example:

> 17 (calculate to row and column for 17-1=16 cause indexes starts at zero)

> 16 = 7 + 7 + 2
> so, 3th row and 2nd column

```
grid[3][2] = "X";
```

then normally print the array it should work as you want.

Comment: Can't store 10 or 42 or any 2 digit number in a chat array, "then fill it with numbers that you use 1..42 in" can keep it null to indicate it's unused. Or use a string array

Comment: Oh, of course thank you. I missed that point.